# document.querySelectorAll doesn't get all the elements on page with lazy loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-scraping

I'm trying to download the audio files available on the following webpage using the Firefox console: https://www.facebook.com/sound/collection/?sound_collection_tab=sound_effects (requires login to Facebook, sorry)

This is the snippet I'm using:

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll('div._661- a[href]:not([href="#"]');
links.forEach( link => setTimeout(link.click(), 500) );
```

The problem is that even if I manually scroll to load all the 1.7K items on the page, `querySelectorAll` only returns 40 elements max. Same thing with `getElementsByTagName`.

I also tried `var n = 0; while (n < 20) {window.scrollTo(0,document.querySelector(".uiScrollableAreaContent").scrollHeight); n++};` to avoid scrolling manually using the mouse wheel but it doesn't seem to do much.

What would be the best way to get all the elements on this type of dynamic / lazy loading scrolling page with Javascript?

Comment: do you "re-run" the `var links = document.querySelectorAll('div._661- a[href]:not([href="#"]');` part?

Comment: It's important to realize document.querySelectorAll only looks at the situation at execution. So if later the amount of results is different, you need to re-run this part of code as Jaromanda X suggested. You can use a function to achieve that. So document.querySelectorAll is by no means real time.

Comment: Not sure what re-run means, but I don't think so. I load the page, scroll to bottom (manually) then open the console, execute `var links = document.querySelectorAll(...)`, then execute `links.length` which returns 40. Am I missing something?

Comment: _“Am I missing something?”_ - select the first `div._661-` element in your DOM inspector, and then start scrolling down, until a couple of new items get loaded … you’ll notice the inspector switching “focus” (the current element it is “on”) to the parent TD element at some time - which indicates that the `div._661-` that you had originally selected was _removed_ from the DOM.

Comment: Looking at it a bit further, you’ll see that they use empty TR elements as the first and last children of the tbody, that get a height of several hundred/thousand pixels assigned to achieve the basic “scrolling” functionality, but in between those there is always a maximum number of 30 TR that holds actual data. Might have performances reasons … or Facebook just wanted to make it a little harder for you to grab all this info.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for investigating @CBroe , I didn't see all of that looking at the Inspector. Webpages are so complicated these days... Well, looks like I'll have to level up my JavaScript. Thanks again.